# Error Installing XML component

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I have just updated my IS2009 ISM to IS2012Spring premier edition. Installer is giving error while deploying. It is perfectly working fine with IS2009 installer. XML code

Please see below logs.

> MSI (s) (78:20) [14:58:09:408]: Executing op:
>   ActionStart(Name=ISXmlInstall,,) Action 14:58:09: ISXmlInstall.  MSI
>   (s) (78:20) [14:58:09:409]: Executing op:
>   CustomActionSchedule(Action=ISXmlInstall,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=ISXmlInstall,CustomActionData=C:\Users\WIN764\AppData\Local\Temp\XML6FE4.tmp)
>   MSI (s) (78:1C) [14:58:09:410]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL:
>   C:\Windows\Installer\MSI988C.tmp, Entrypoint: ISXmlInstall
>   InstallShield 14:58:09: Installing 1 XML component(s) InstallShield
>   14:58:09: Installing XML Component 'SebringAppConfig.xml'
>   InstallShield 14:58:09: Installing XML file 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Pitney Bowes\SureTrac\Client\Data\SebringAppConfig.xml'
>   InstallShield 14:58:09: Using MSXML version 6 InstallShield 14:58:09:
>   Processing XPath '//' InstallShield 14:58:09: No namespace for prefix
>   pi found InstallShield 14:58:09: Node name: 'pi:APPLICATION'  -->
>   Attribute name = 'pi:AppPath', Current Value = '', Operation = '1'
>   InstallShield 14:58:09: Node name: 'pi:APPLICATION'  - Attribute name
>   = 'pi:AppPath', Old Value = '',  New value = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Pitney Bowes\SureTrac\Client\', Actual New Value = 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Pitney Bowes\SureTrac\Client\' CustomAction ISXmlInstall
>   returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if
>   translation happened inside sandbox) Action ended 14:58:09:
>   InstallExecute. Return value 3.

I have config file added in component AppConfigFiles also a separate component as SebringAppConfig.xml.

Please see attached image.

[image: XML View]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have figured it out. Needed to add PI in namespace